# How to safely read a text file that might be binary?

Tags: java, out-of-memory

We have some Java code that processes a **user-provided file** by looping through the file using  `BufferedReader.readline()` to read in each line.

The problem is that when the user uploads a file that has extremely long lines, like an arbitrary binary JPG or such, this can cause out-of-memory issues.  Even the first `readline()` may not return.  **We want to reject the files with long lines before it OOMs.**

Is there a standard Java idiom to handle this, or do we just change to `read()` and write our own safe version of `readLine()`?

Comment: What happens if the user uploads a valid text file which just has an extremely long line? Do you still want to filter that out?

Comment: Our max would be 5k characters or so, while these test files haves lines containing millions of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to read the file character by character (or chunk by chunk) yourself (via some form of read()), and then form the lines into Strings when you encounter a newline character.  This way you can throw an Exception (avoiding the OOM error) if some maximum number of characters is hit before a newline is encountered.

If you use a Reader instance it should not be too difficult to implement this code, just read from the Reader into a buffer (which you allocate to your maximum possible line length), and then convert the buffer to String when you encounter a newline (or throw an exception if you don't).

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be any way to set a line length limit for BufferedReader.readLine(), so it will accumulate the entire line before feeding it to your code, however long that line may be.

Therefore, you'll have to do the line-splitting part yourself, and give up once a line is too long.

You might use the following as a starting point:

```
class LineTooLongException extends Exception {}

class ShortLineReader implements AutoCloseable {
    final Reader reader;

    final char[] buf = new char[8192];
    int nextIndex = 0;
    int maxIndex = 0;
    boolean eof;

    public ShortLineReader(Reader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public String readLine() throws IOException, LineTooLongException {
        if (eof) {
            return null;
        }
        for (;;) {

            for (int i = nextIndex; i < maxIndex; i++) {
                if (buf[i] == '\n') {
                    String result = new String(buf, nextIndex, i - nextIndex);
                    nextIndex = i + 1;
                    return result;
                }
            }
            if (maxIndex - nextIndex > 6000) {
                throw new LineTooLongException();
            } 
            System.arraycopy(buf, nextIndex, buf, 0, maxIndex - nextIndex);
            maxIndex -= nextIndex;
            nextIndex = 0;
            int c = reader.read(buf, maxIndex, buf.length - maxIndex);
            if (c == -1) {
                eof = true;
                return new String(buf, nextIndex, maxIndex - nextIndex);
            } else {
                maxIndex += c;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        reader.close();
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("D:\\t\\output.log");
//      try (OutputStream fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
//          for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
//              fos.write(65);
//          }
//      }

        try (ShortLineReader r = new ShortLineReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String s;
            while ((s = r.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Note: This assumes unix-style line termination.

Answer (score 0):

Use BufferedInputStream to read binary data rather than BufferedReader... 
for example if it is an image file, using ImageIO and InputStream you can do it like this..

```
 File file = new File("image.gif");
image = ImageIO.read(file);

InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("image.gif"));
image = ImageIO.read(is);
```

hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a definite way but a few things you can do:

1. Check file headers. jMimeMagic seems to be a pretty good library for this purpose.
2. Check the type of characters the file contains. Essentially do statistical analysis on the first 'x' bytes of the file and use that to estimate the rest of the content.
3. Check for newlines '\n' or '\r' in the files, binary files usually wont contain newlines.

Hope that helps.